# How do you call a table that contains static id-value, for reference by other tables?

Tags: database-design, terminology

How do you call a table that just contains a static list of ids and static values, whose purpose is to be referenced by other tables?

For instance, a `countries` table like `1:Fiji,2:Cuba.3:Peru,...`. Then a `users` table contains for each user the id of the country they were born in.

How would you call the `countries` table? I used to know it as a "master table", but most Google results use it with other meanings. Is there a better word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lookup Table" is probably what you are after here.

Answer (score 0):

You call it a table.

I glanced through the indexes in all my books on relational databases. Not a single one had an entry like "lookup table", "master table", or "junction table".  There's a reason.